# How do I get ConstraintLayout to reach the app bar when I start the application

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I have a ConstraintLayout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ui.dictionary.DictionaryFragment">


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextSearch"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:autofillHints=""
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:hint="Enter word"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnSubmit"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSubmit"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:text="Search"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextSearch" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Which looks like this in the preview:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJqy1.png)

However when I run the app the searchbar doesn't seem to reach the top of the app bar.
How can I fix this?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hubCp.png)

This is the way it looks with a red layout:
[image]

Comment: Add a background color to your ConstraintLayout to verify whether the white bar is actually due to the ConstraintLayout. It's the exact height of a Toolbar, so I'm thinking it's due to something else.

Comment: It ends at the top of the search bar. Not sure how to extend it, in the java file maybe? The name of the app bar is also different which wasn't really my intention ahah

Comment: Your fragment in activity doesn't match parent. or isn't aligned to the top of the parent. Can You add activity XML?

Comment: Your problem is not in the posted code. It's possibly in `activity_main.xml`, or perhaps even due to something strange you did in `styles.xml`. Or maybe even in your Fragment's Java/Kotlin code.